# Obtener si una fecha es Ayer, Hoy, Mañana en Android

Tags: java, android

Partiendo de una fecha `yyy-MM-dd` como se puede obtener si fue ayer, si es hoy, o bien mañana.

Para saber si la fecha es el día actual, uso

```
Date anivDate = datePattern.parse("2017-09-28");
if (DateUtils.isToday(anivDate.getTime())) ...
```

Me falta para saber si fue ayer y mañana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si es hoy puedes usar el Método que muestras:

```
DateUtils.isToday(date);
```

puedes agregar un día o restar para comparar si es ayer u hoy

Método para comprobar si la fecha es de **ayer**:

```
public static boolean isYesterday(long date) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    cdate.setTimeInMillis(date);

    now.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    return now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cdate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            && now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cdate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            && now.get(Calendar.DATE) == cdate.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Método para comprobar si la fecha es de **mañana**:

```
public static boolean isTomorrow(long date) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    cdate.setTimeInMillis(date);

    now.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);

    return now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cdate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            && now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cdate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            && now.get(Calendar.DATE) == cdate.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

para homologar, otro método para saber si es el día de **hoy**

```
public static boolean isToday(long date){
    return DateUtils.isToday(date);
}
```

---

Ejemplos de uso:

```
 SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date fecha  = datePattern.parse("2017-09-30");

 if (isYesterday(fecha.getTime())){
    ....
    ....

 if (isToday(fecha.getTime())){
    ....
    ....

 if (isTomorrow(fecha.getTime())){
    ....
    ....
```